# Add view count on post page

Tags: feature-request, views, information-display

When I ask a question I like to keep the page on it (with auto-refresh set), so that I can see the answers as soon as they show up.  It'd be nice to see how many views the question has been getting without having to go back to the 'questions' page.

It seems like we could add the view count to the post view.

Comment: I've voted to close as no longer relevant, thanks to Juan's relevant answer.

Comment: lol [char limit]

Comment: I think it should remain, for future feature-requests

Comment: @Lance: I can chastise you more by voting to close as blatantly offensive. Just tell me your wishes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[alt text http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/so1.png](http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/so1.png)

Comment: Damn. Beat me by 30 seconds. This free-hand circle requirement is such a productivity/time killer.

Comment: With freehand circle for your viewing pleasure

Comment: you beat my comment by 11 seconds

Comment: I'm properly chastised, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Someone should replace that screenshot to include a screenshot of this answer which includes a screenshot of this answer which includes...

Comment: Image is dead, do you happen to have it mirrored somewhere, or can come with a new one? Otherwise better delete the answer.